# how to call pointer function

Tags: c, pointers

Please tell me how to call the function `twoSum` below. It uses the data type `int*`. I do not know how to do that. Thank you .

```
#include <stdio.h>

//int twoSum(nums, target);
int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    int nums[10]= {2,7,11,15};
    int target = 9;
    int numsSize=3;
    int retrunSize=3;
    int a=twoSum(nums,numsSize,target,retrunSize);
    return 0;
}

int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numsSize; ++j) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                int* ret = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
                ret[0] = i, ret[1] = j;
                *returnSize = 2;
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }

    *returnSize = 0;
    return NULL;
}
```

With the helpful advice in the comment, I get the modified version. But `printf(a)` give me nothing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//int twoSum(nums, target);
#include <stdlib.h>
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numsSize; ++j) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                int* ret = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
                ret[0] = i, ret[1] = j;
                *returnSize = 2;
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
    *returnSize = 0;
    return NULL;
}
int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    int nums[4]= {2,7,11,15};
    int target = 13;
    int numsSize=6;
    int retrunSize=0;
    int* a=twoSum(nums,numsSize,target,retrunSize);
    printf(&a);
    printf(*a);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what the debugger shows:

[image: Debugger output]

Comment: `int *nums[10]= {2,7,11,15};` should at least be [issuing warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/o6xvzqW4h). If it isn't, your warning paranoia settings need to raise the bar. That leading `*` should not be there.

Comment: `twoSums` requires 4 arguments. Your code only provides two. Two is not four.

Comment: @KenWhite    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    int nums[10]= {2,7,11,15};
    int target = 9;
    int numsSize=3;
    int retrunSize=3;
    int a=twoSum(nums,numsSize,target,retrunSize);
    return 0;

Comment: @KenWhite like that? still get error

Comment: Don't post code walls in comments. Add a new code listing [**to your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70719047/edit). And your question should contain an accurate description of what your program is supposed to be doing, how you're trying to do it, and what it seems to actually be doing, etc. It's hard enough to debug other peoples code; don't make it harder by also requiring us to decipher it's intended purpose. If you're experiencing errors, *they belong in your question as well*, verbatim.

Comment: `twoSum` returns an `int*`, but you're assigning it to an `int` ... and not using the return value for anything anyway.

Comment: @WhozCraig modify that already ,still get error

Comment: You also need to `#include <stdlib.h>` for `malloc`, and either move your `twoSum` function above `main` or add a function declaration for it above `main`. The compiler reads top to bottom, and the first time it encounters `twoSum` in `main` it doesn't know what it is.

Comment: @yano can you tell me how to get the return value of the twoSum function and print it

Comment: You're capturing the return value (a pointer) in `a`. I assume you want to print the value it points to.. `printf("%d\n", *a);`. The `*` in this context dereferences it, `"%d"` says you want to print an `int`. Some basic internet searching about how to use [`printf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) would've led you to that answer much more quickly than waiting for a reply.

Comment: @oh yes,thanks lot for your kindly remind

Comment: @yano I get used to python like print(a),but in c it is printf("%d\n", *a)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can refer below,

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numsSize; ++j) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                int* ret = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
                ret[0] = i, ret[1] = j;
                *returnSize = 2;
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
    *returnSize = 0;
    return NULL;
}
 
    //int twoSum(nums, target);
    int main() {
        printf("Hello, World!\n");
        int i;
        int* (*funptr)(int*, int, int, int*) = &twoSum; // function pointer declaration
        int nums[10] = {2,7,11,15};
        int target = 9;
        int *returnSize = malloc(sizeof(int)); // need returnsize pointer vairable to collect return size
        int *a=(*funptr)(nums, 10, target, returnSize); // function pointer calling
        // Below are output statements
        printf("returnSize = %d\n", *returnSize);
        printf("Nums porsition are: ");
        for (i = 0; i < *returnSize; i++) {
            printf ("a[%d] = %d ", i, a[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. Also see [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/172661) for more information.

Comment: I will get your answer one day ,but not today. thank you for your effort@Magesh